# For Next loop unexpectedly skipping some entries when trying to trigger macro for multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to trigger a macro when I change multiple cells with CTRL+ENTER for each cell separately.

The code sometimes skips rows. What could be causing this some cells scattered within the range?

```vb
    ChangeCell = Target.Address(0, 0)
    ' In case of multiple changed cells, RowChangeCell provides the 1st row of the changed range
    RowChangeCell = Range(ChangeCell).Row
           
    Range(ChangeCell).Select
    With Selection
        ChangeStart = .Cells(1, 1).Address
        ChangeEnd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Address
        ChangeStartRow = Range(ChangeStart).Row
        ChangeEndRow = Range(ChangeEnd).Row
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
              
    'If Not Intersection Is Nothing Then
        
        'ChangeCell = Target.Address(0, 0)
        'ActiveRowMain = Range(ChangeCell).Row
                
        For ActiveRowMain = ChangeStartRow To ChangeEndRow Step 1
            
            'If ActiveRowMain = 51055 Then
            '
            '    Chck = Worksheets("Main_Report").Range("A" & ActiveRowMain).Value
            '    MsgBox "Status = " & Chck
            '
            'End If
        
            'Chck = Worksheets("Main_Report").Range("A" & ActiveRowMain).Value
            'MsgBox "MainLine = " & ActiveRowMain & " Status = " & Chck & " ChangeStartRow = " & ChangeStartRow & " ChangeEndRow = " & ChangeEndRow
            
            Call Events_Update_Main_Caller(ActiveRowMain)
            
        Next ActiveRowMain
        
        'MsgBox "Updates are completed"
         
    'End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, but `RowChangeCell = Range(ChangeCell).Row` can just be `RowChangeCell = ChangeCell.Row`.  Does `Events_Update_Main_Caller` use `Activate` or `Select` at all?

Comment: Actually this is not what I want to do. When a cell changes it triggers a macro. But is it possible to do this for multiple cells (not necessarily consecutive) when I select them, make a change and press CTRL+ENTER?

Comment: If they're not consecutive, then you need to loop over their `Areas`

Comment: thank you for the comment, any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Something like `For Each rng in Target.Areas`, then `For Each cell in rng`.